# Rename Menus in Magento 1.7

Tags: magento, menu

Have a Magento 1.7 template with three left side vertical menus, Accordion, CSS and Mega and all menus are respectively named instead of Categories. I can rename CSS menu easily via its phtml file, but the other two seem to be impossible to rename. Their phtml look nothing like the CSS menu and appear to have hash data, my guess from the template developer. I have done a search on my entire site and database and I can't figure out where it is pulling the name from (I have spent an embarrassing amount of time on this). I have asked the developer, but they refuse to answer a “Magento” question. The Accordion menu is also the only menu I can get to work where the products show on the home page and when you click on a category the page displays correctly. If I use CSS menu it will display products on the home page, but when you click on the category it doesn’t appear to be pulling the CSS formatting.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

/app/design/frontend/default//locale/en_US/translate.csv
Enter as: "Accordion Menu","Categories"